# Why won't SDL detect my iBuffalo game controller on Linux (PocketCHIP)?

Tags: linux, sdl, sdl-2, gamepad, gamecontroller

I recently obtained an ARM-based Linux computer called a [PocketCHIP](https://getchip.com/pages/pocketchip). It's a great little computer! I'm working on writing a program which uses SDL 2.0.4 and my [iBuffalo USB gamepad](http://amzn.to/29mr0nF). However, SDL does not seem to recognize the controller on the PocketCHIP. I think this is a popular controller, so it would surprise me if SDL did not already support it, which makes me think that there's something wrong with my setup/installation. The controller does work in other programs though (mednafen).

On my Mac, when I run the `testgamecontroller.c`, `testjoystick.c`, and `controllermap.c` scripts that are included in the SDL test directory, they all recognize the controller correctly:

```
INFO: Joystick 0: USB,2-axis 8-button gamepad   (guid 83050000000000006020000000000000)
INFO: There are 0 game controller(s) attached (1 joystick(s))
```

However, when I run the same scripts on the PocketCHIP, it does not detect the controller.

```
INFO: There are 0 game controller(s) attached (0 joystick(s))
```

Linux does seem to recognize the device as connected though:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
...

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0583 Product=2060 Version=0110
N: Name="USB,2-axis 8-button gamepad  "
P: Phys=usb-1c14400.usb-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc@01c00000/1c14400.usb/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:0583:2060.0003/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=js0 event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=ff 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
B: MSC=10
```

What do I need to do to get SDL to recognize my controller on the PocketCHIP?

Comment: Does your user account have [read permissions on the joystick file](https://bbs.nextthing.co/t/usb-controller-for-pico-8-on-pocketc-h-i-p/5077/11)?

Comment: @genpfault That was it!!! I added the chip user to the input group and now SDL is detecting my controller. Thanks!

Comment: @genpfault: feel free to copy/paste my answer below and I will accept it to give you credit.

Comment: I'm good, thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @genpfault, I learned that SDL uses `/dev/input/event*` for gamepad input capture. However, my user (`chip`) did not have permission to access these, so it was failing silently.

To grant the `chip` user access, add the chip user to the `input` group.

On Debian Linux you can simply run:

```
sudo adduser chip input
```

Or you can manually do it by editing `/etc/group`:

```
sudo nano /etc/group
```

Arrow down to the line that says:

```
input:x:101:
```

to:

```
input:x:101:chip
```

Type `control+x`, to exit. It will prompt you to save the file. Type `y`, then `return` to save the file and quit the nano text editor. Restart your PocketCHIP and SDL will now be able to read the gamepad input.